# MODX - quip display extended field - photo using phpthumbof

Tags: modx

- Quip

  - phpthumbof

I have Quip running on my site and I am using a snippet to call a extended profile field from the author of the comment to display the user profile image.

**SNIPPET**

```
<?php
if (!empty($userid)) {
$user = $modx->getObject('modUserProfile', array('id' => $userid) );
$extendedfields = $user->get('extended');
$output = $extendedfields[$field];
}
if (isset($output)) { return $output;}
return $default;
```

In my Quip.comment TPL

```
 <div class="quip-comment-right">
<img src="[[!quip_profile_image? &userid=`[[+author]]` &field=`nomination_file` &default=`text`]]" />
     </div>
```

The above works perfectly and I can see the image, but I cant figure out how to add PHPthumbof, to change size etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = $modx->runSnippet('phpthumbof',array(
   'input' => $output,
   'options' => '&w=640&h=480&zc=0&aoe=0&far=0'
));
```

Comment: Hi Vasis - wheer do I add that . Directly into the existing snippet ?

Comment: Yes, before `return $output;`